# Skip Jenkins Pipeline Steps If Node Is Offline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline job that, for part of the build, uses a node with a lot of downtime. I'd like this step performed if the node is online and skipped without failing the build if the node is offline.

This is related, but different from the problem of [skipping parts of a Matrix Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7891709/336925).

I tried to programmatically check if a node is online like so.

```
jenkins.model.Nodes.getNode('my-node').toComputer().isOnline()
```

This runs up against the Jenkins security sandbox:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified method java.lang.Class getNode java.lang.String
```

I tried setting a timeout that will be tripped if the node is offline.

```
try {
    timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
        node('my-node') {
            // Do optional step
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    echo 'Time out on optional step. Node down?'
}
```

This has a major downside. I have to know what the longest time the step would take, then wait even longer when the node is down. I tried working around that with a "canary" step:

```
try {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'SECONDS') {
        node('my-node') {
            echo 'Node is up. Performing optional step.'
        }
    }
    node('my-node') {
        echo 'This is an optional step.'
    }
} catch (e) {
    echo 'Time out on optional step. Node down?'
}
```

This skips the step if the node is up, but busy with another job. This is the best solution I have come up with so far. Is there just a way to check if the node is online without using a timeout?

Comment: Have you tried approving the getNode method for use in sandbox?

Comment: I just tried to run it again. I can't get it to show up in "In-process Script Approval". Other methods (like `method java.lang.Throwable printStackTrace`) show up there when I get a sandbox rejection. Any other way to approve the method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work:

`Jenkins.instance.getNode('my-node').toComputer().isOnline()`

see http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html

Comment: That worked! I had to make 5 round trips between failed builds and "In-process Script Approval", but it worked!

Comment: Note of warning: I just updated to Jenkins ver. 2.32.3 and was notified that Jenkins.getInstance (required for this answer to work) "may have introduced a security vulnerability". The tool "recommends clearing" the signature. In other words, this answer no longer works. :(

Comment: @JamesMarble have you found another way to check if the node is running and skip the step otherwise?

Comment: Nothing yet. My need for this has been overcome by events, so I suspect I won't find a solution myself. Happy to test any other answers that come up!

Comment: A hideously ugly way is:
`https://YOURJENKINS/computer/YOURSLAVENAME/api/json?tree=offline`

That will return something like this: `{"_class":"hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer","offline":false}`

Or more succintly:

`https://YOURJENKINS/computer/YOURSLAVE/api/xml?xpath=//offline/text()` which will return `true` or `false`

The reason I say it's ugly is you'll have to supply credentials and use the REST api.

Comment: @Steven the Easily Amused: The XPath expression renders a HTTP 403 ('primitive XPath result sets forbidden; implement jenkins.security.SecureRequester') in my Jenkins installation (v2.76).

Comment: @Florian:  I just used exactly this: `https://YOURJENKINS/computer/YOURSLAVE/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=//offline/text()` and I too got errors the first two times. Somehow it magically worked on the third time. It worked without the depth parameter, too.

Oh, and this will tell if the master is online:
`.../computer/(master)/api/xml?xpath=//offline/text()`

We are using: CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise 2.73.1.2

Comment: I seriously don't understand the model security of Jenkins if asking whether a node is alive is considered a potential security threat. :/

Answer (score 14):

There is a pipeline call for this.

```
nodesByLabel 'my-node'
```

Returns `[]` if no node is online; returns `arraylist` with online instances otherwise.

Comment: works out of the box, no script approval needed :)  running jenkins v 2.231

Comment: Solution shall be upvoted. This is easy and works fine. NOTE: nodesByLabel is available via plugin "Pipeline Utility Steps", which is anyway very useful for different tasks.

Comment: This is the hassle free solution.

Answer (score 5):

I simply did this:

```
 pipeline {
     agent none
     environment { AGENT_NODE = "somenode" }
     stages {
         stage('Offline Node') {
             when {
                 beforeAgent true
                 expression {
                     return nodesByLabel(env.AGENT_NODE).size() > 0
                 }

             }
             agent {
                  label "${env.AGENT_NODE}"
             }
             steps {
                  ...
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: In declarative pipeline I see "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'nodesByLabel' found among steps".