# Jenkins pipeline queue gets full when all agents are offline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a Jenkins pipeline script and when all nodes are offline, the builds keep on queuing up. How do I stop Jenkins from adding jobs to the queue while all slaves are offline?

```
pipeline {
  triggers {
      pollSCM('H/3 * * * 1-5')

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is your agent's availability configured to 'Keep this agent online as much as possible' ?

One way to tackle this situation is, run the below script on master node and build your pipeline(s) only if at least one of the nodes is online. You can pass the online node name to your downstream job as a parameter.

```
def axis = []
for (slave in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getNodes()) {
 if (slave.toComputer().isOnline()) {
    axis += slave.getDisplayName()
 }
}
return axis
```

Above script source: [Jenkins: skip if node is offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891709/jenkins-skip-if-node-is-offline?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Other links that may help are:

Monitor and restart your slave nodes - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Monitor+and+Restart+Offline+Slaves

I found this script handy in some situations:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/clearBuildQueue.groovy

Comment: How would I add this little script in my pipeline? Between which brackets should I put it? trigger {}? Or agent{}?

Comment: Neither. trigger{} and agent{} are not used for running script. Execute it within a stage

Comment: Ok, but that would mean that the build queue will still pile up and the build numbers keep increasing, right?

Comment: Oh the node online script. Run it as a new pipeline on master node and build your other pipeline only if at least one node is online otherwise don’t build. Pass the online node name as parameter to your downstream pipeline. So, jobs wont queue up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into pipeline jobs, but for regular freestyle jobs, this kind of queueing will only  happen if your builds are parameterized. Seperate builds are needed then to ensure that the project will run seperately for each and every parameter value (it does not matter whether the value is actually different).

So, removing build parameters in your project might solve the problem.

Comment: This build script doesn't contain any parameters. It is a multibranch pipeline script and currently just runs on the 'master' branch.

Comment: Possibly this is internally the same root cause. Could you move the mouse pointer over the queue entries -- possibly there's some addtional information visible in the "mouseover" window that indicates the difference between the queued entries.